# Is there a way to decide where the bullets appear on the length of my ship, regardless of the ships angle?

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

I have been trying to make the bullets come out from a specific point on my ship (a pixel ship, where I have drawn a "cannon"). It works when the ship is in a specific angle, but as soon as the player rotate the ship, the bullets start appearing further and further away from the cannon.

I have been trying to work out the math behind fixing this, but cannot for the life of me figure it out. I have tried playing with offset values within the Bullet class, adding it to the blit_rotate_center function as arguments for the x and y values. Everything I do seem to make it worse.

```
    new_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rotated_image = pygame.mask.from_surface(new_image)
    new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = image.get_rect(topleft = top_left).center)
    
    
    win.blit(rotated_image.to_surface(unsetcolor=(0, 0, 0, 0), setcolor= (255, 255, 255,)), new_rect.topleft)
    win.blit(new_image, new_rect.topleft)
    return new_rect

class PlayerShip:
    def __init__(self):
        self.img = assets.SPACE_SHIP_1
        self.max_vel = 3
        self.vel = 0
        self.acceleration = 0.01
        self.rotation_vel = 0.0
        self.rotation_max_vel = 0.6
        self.rotation_acc = 0.01
        self.angle = 270
        self.x = 400
        self.y = 400
        self.drag = 0.004
        self.rotation_drag = 0.0025
        self.vertical = 0
        self.horizontal = 0
        self.cooldown = 240
        self.max_cooldown = 240
        self.rect = self.img.get_rect()

        # Weapons data
        self.salvo = 3

        
    
    def rotate(self, left = False, right = False):
        if left:
            self.rotation_vel += self.rotation_acc
            if self.rotation_vel > self.rotation_max_vel:
                self.rotation_vel = self.rotation_max_vel
        elif right:
            self.rotation_vel -= self.rotation_acc
            if self.rotation_vel < self.rotation_max_vel - self.rotation_max_vel * 2:
                self.rotation_vel = self.rotation_max_vel - self.rotation_max_vel * 2
    
    def draw(self, win):
        self.rect = blit_rotate_center(win, self.img, (self.x, self.y), self.angle)
        self.angle += self.rotation_vel
        # Moving the player according to angle
        radians = math.radians(self.angle)
        self.vertical = math.cos(radians) * self.vel
        self.horizontal = math.sin(radians) * self.vel
        self.y -= self.vertical
        self.x -= self.horizontal
        self.reduce_speed()

        #Updating the cooldown
        self.cooldown -= 1
        if self.cooldown <= 0:
            self.cooldown = 0

    def key_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rotate(left = True)
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rotate(right = True)
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.move_forward()
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.move_backward()
    
    def move_forward(self):
        self.img = assets.SPACE_SHIP_1_THRUST
        self.vel = min(self.vel + self.acceleration, self.max_vel)

    def move_backward(self):
        self.vel = min(self.vel - self.acceleration, self.max_vel)
        if self.vel < self.max_vel - self.max_vel * 2:
            self.vel = self.max_vel - self.max_vel * 2
    
    def reduce_speed(self):
        if self.vel < 0:
            self.vel += self.drag
        elif self.vel > 0:
            self.vel -= self.drag
        if self.rotation_vel < 0:
            self.rotation_vel += self.rotation_drag
        elif self.rotation_vel > 0:
            self.rotation_vel -= self.rotation_drag




class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, player_angle, player_rect):
        self.speed = 10
        self.angle = player_angle
        self.image = assets.BULLET_1

        ship_center_x = player_rect[0] + player_rect[2] // 2
        ship_center_y = player_rect[1] + player_rect[3] // 2

        self.x = ship_center_x
        self.y = ship_center_y

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        radians = math.radians(self.angle - 90)
        self.vertical = math.cos(radians) * self.speed
        self.horizontal = math.sin(radians) * self.speed


        self.x_offset = self.vertical
        self.y_offset = self.horizontal
    
    
    def draw(self, win):
        blit_rotate_center(win, self.image, (self.x - self.x_offset, self.y - self.y_offset), self.angle)
        radians = math.radians(self.angle - 90)
        self.vertical = math.cos(radians) * self.speed
        self.horizontal = math.sin(radians) * self.speed
        self.y -= self.vertical
        self.x -= self.horizontal
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem here is that you're not correctly calculating the offset from the center of the ship to the cannon for different angles. In a rotated coordinate system, the x and y offsets change depending on the angle. Therefore, you have to take the rotation of the ship into account when determining the position of the cannon.

To do this, you should:

1. Determine the offset of the cannon from the center of the ship in the ship's local coordinate system. This will be a constant pair of x, y values.
2. Rotate this offset by the same angle as the ship to get the offset in the global (screen) coordinate system. This can be done using a simple rotation matrix.
3. Add this rotated offset to the center of the ship to get the global position of the cannon.

Here's how you can modify your `Bullet` class to implement this:

```py
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, player_angle, player_rect):
        self.speed = 10
        self.angle = player_angle
        self.image = assets.BULLET_1

        ship_center_x = player_rect[0] + player_rect[2] // 2
        ship_center_y = player_rect[1] + player_rect[3] // 2

        # Step 1: Define the offset from the center of the ship to the cannon in the ship's local coordinates.
        # These values depend on how your ship is drawn.
        local_cannon_offset_x = 0
        local_cannon_offset_y = -20  # Assuming the cannon is 20 pixels above the center of the ship.

        # Step 2: Rotate the local offset by the same angle as the ship to get the offset in the global coordinate system.
        # We use the standard rotation matrix here.
        radians = math.radians(self.angle)
        global_cannon_offset_x = local_cannon_offset_x * math.cos(radians) - local_cannon_offset_y * math.sin(radians)
        global_cannon_offset_y = local_cannon_offset_x * math.sin(radians) + local_cannon_offset_y * math.cos(radians)

        # Step 3: Add the global offset to the center of the ship to get the position of the cannon.
        self.x = ship_center_x + global_cannon_offset_x
        self.y = ship_center_y + global_cannon_offset_y

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        radians = math.radians(self.angle - 90)
        self.vertical = math.cos(radians) * self.speed
        self.horizontal = math.sin(radians) * self.speed

    def draw(self, win):
        blit_rotate_center(win, self.image, (self.x, self.y), self.angle)
        radians = math.radians(self.angle - 90)
        self.vertical = math.cos(radians) * self.speed
        self.horizontal = math.sin(radians) * self.speed
        self.y -= self.vertical
        self.x -= self.horizontal
```